# Multiple markers with Infowindows are not proper in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have displayed multiple markers on google map with infowindows clicking on markers.

But i am not getting infowindows at the top of the markers.Actually it is displaying on other palce on google map.

And another problem is with overlapped markers.There is displaying just one infowindows.

My code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/11/

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerArray[i][2], markerArray[i][1]),
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: 'M76,76L115.83716857408419,53A46,46,0,0,1,121.748,80.8083L76,76A0,0,0,0,0,76,76',
            fillColor: color[i],
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor: '',
            strokeWeight: 0,
            scale: 0.9,
            rotation: 280 + markerArray[i][3],
        },
    });
```

so, how can i solve these issues. Please help me!!

Comment: Is the SVG symbol itself placed at the right spot? Look at the `anchor` property of the icon object: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon For the overlapping issue, it seems that your SVG canvas is actually bigger than what is rendered.

Comment: yes, i see.

so, is there any way to make smaller that SVG canvas.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: duplicate of [Custom Marker on Google maps api issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059551/custom-marker-on-google-maps-api-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your infowindows are shifted, so for fixing that problem you can add a new option `pixelOffset` here you can find more about that option: [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions).

Basicly I fixed your problem by adding this option to your code:

```
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, +50)
```

Here you can see my quick fix: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/12/)

For your overlapping problem I'm suggesting you to use this: [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)

It resolved all my overlaping problems

Comment: Thanks For solving infowindow position related issue.

Comment: But, there is also problem : if you click on blue marker then it displays yellow marker infowindow. Pls check that

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem right now, but yes, I noticed that problem. In this case second click would show right content.... Do you have any special reason for drawing markers? Obviously these drawings covers much more space on map than we can see

Comment: If I click near marker (a few centimeters away) it will show it's infowindow. That means that you are showing triangles on your map, but they cover much more surface although it is not colored

Comment: yes, i see that this marker covers much more space on the map.

Comment: have you any idea about to create this type of slice which can cover less space on map

Comment: The simplest idea is to set url of your icon. Instead of drawing it I would prefer using completed one

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/u758rqpa/15/)</kbd>

I created a similar slice symbol and aligned it on the upper left corner of the canvas. I have added the anchor point as well:

```
icon: {
    path: 'm 32.460621,0.112468 -32.372233,-0.022 0,-0.088 L 0,0.090468 l 22.91468,22.9147 c 0.02205,-0.022 0.04437,-0.044 0.06629,-0.066 6.300656,-6.3007 9.451842,-14.5699 9.47965,-22.8263 z',

    fillColor: color[i],
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '',
    strokeWeight: 0,
    rotation: 280 + markerA[i][3],
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
}
```

I have added a standard marker for reference, so that you can see where the real coordinates are and how your symbol is placed relatively on the map. Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you create yours? I created this one with Inkscape. Other tools will do the job too.

Comment: ok, i got that svg from googling.. Have you any tool name to create this ?

Comment: can you please create this slice with different angles ? For Example I have value 60 then slice will be with 60 degree angle. Then others will be different angles.

Comment: This is what you are doing with the `rotation` property, isn't it?

Comment: no, not to rotate that. But i have to create that with 60 degree angel

Comment: Here is different pie slice with different angels. http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/creating-a-svg-pie-chart-html5/

Comment: Sorry but no. This is not a site to request others to do work for you. Download [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/download) and learn how to use it and create your own SVG.